# Referencing a FileHandle as an Array

Tags: arrays, perl, pointers, filehandle

Given that I have a 4GB file I need to process, is there a way in Perl where I can reference a filehandle like an array without copying it into an actual array/memory?

Something like:

```
open (LOG, "less file.txt |");
my @reference = \<LOG>;
print $reference[1000000];
close LOG;
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-File/lib/Tie/File.pm).

```
use Tie::File;
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', $filename or die "tie $filename: $!";

print $array[42];
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't need the contents of the whole file though. I have to grep and awk it before I read it in.

Comment: Why not grep and awk it in Perl, then?